# Excel macro works first time then very slow next time

Tags: excel, vba

So while running my macro in an unshared sheet it works perfectly fine no issues, soon as i share it usually the first time will run fine, but the second time takes forever.

If after the first time i run the macro i close the workbook and reopen it will run fine again.

i have tried to clear the clipboard and also tried another version of clearing a clip board using a macro. which makes no difference.

i have tied all sorts to get this work even going back to basics.

simple clear sheet, open workbook, select range, copy, paste into sheet. (also tried value=value and array)

Status bar shows filling cells and slow progress, no matter if 1000 lines or 10,0000 lines (only copying around 10,000 lines)

Im really stumped and what to try next.

See code i was using earlier,

```
Sub Macro4()
    
    Dim MyDate As String
    Dim MyTime As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim MyCriteria As String
    Dim WFile As String
    Dim CopyFile As String
    Dim CopyFile1 As String
    Dim BackupCopy As String
    Dim dt As Date
    Dim dt2 As Date
    
    Dim FSO As Object
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    MyDate = Format(Now, "DD.MM.YY")
    MyTime = Format(Now, "HH.MM.SS")
    MyFile = ThisWorkbook.Name
    
    MyCriteria = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Range("F1").Value
    WFile = "file_export.csv"
    CopyFile = "file.csv"
    CopyFile1 = "copy"
    BackupCopy = "file_backup.csv"
    
    'dt = Format(wb.Sheets("Dotcom").Range("F1"), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    dt = wb.Sheets("Dotcom").Range("F1")
    dt2 = dt - 1
    
    'Now2 = CDate(Now() - 1) 'formatting the date using the CDate function
    'Now2 = Format(Now2, "MM/DD/YYYY") 'formatting the date by dropping the hour
    
    'dt2 = CDate(dt2) 'formatting the date using the CDate function
    'dt2 = Format(dt2, "MM/DD/YYYY") 'formatting the date by dropping the hour
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    For N = 1 To 9
        With wb.Sheets("Day" & N)
            .UsedRange.Columns("A:G").Clear
        End With
    Next
    
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
    Workbooks.Open ("c:\scripts\" & CopyFile)
    
    With Workbooks(CopyFile).Sheets(CopyFile1)
        With .UsedRange
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" & MyCriteria
            .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
            .AutoFilter
        End With
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
    End With
    
    For N = 1 To 9
        With wb.Sheets("Day" & N)
            .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        End With
    Next
        
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Workbooks(CopyFile).Close savechanges:=False
    
    For N = 1 To 9
        With wb.Sheets("Day" & N)
            With .UsedRange.Columns("A:G")
                .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<" & CLng(dt2), _
                    Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=">=" & CLng(dt2) + 1
                .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
                .AutoFilter
            End With
    
            dt2 = dt2 + 1
        End With
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to see your code

Comment: Can you clarify which part of the code is particularly slow? Also [this article](https://analystcave.com/excel-improve-vba-performance/) might be of interest

Comment: i have tried a simple copy and paste, when the sheet is in shared thats when i see issues with it being slow etc, once unshared copy paste is fine. Seems like the first time it runs in shared or after closing and reopening the file it runs fine. almost like like its not clearing correctly / closing file. i have tried clearing clipboard etc but still nothing,

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid copy/paste with direct copy

```vb
    With Workbooks(CopyFile).Sheets(CopyFile1)
        With .UsedRange
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" & MyCriteria
            .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
            .AutoFilter
        End With
        
        For n = 1 To 9
            .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy _ 
             wb.Sheets("Day" & n).Range("A1")
        Next
    End With
```

Alternatively just copy the records you want

```vb
Dim wbCSV As Workbook
Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open("c:\scripts\" & CopyFile, ReadOnly:=True)
With wbCSV.Sheets(1).UsedRange
    For n = 1 To 9
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & MyCriteria
        .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=" & dt2
        wb.Sheets("Day" & n).UsedRange.Columns("A:G").Clear
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy  _ 
        wb.Sheets("Day" & n).Range("A1")
        dt2 = dt2 + 1
    Next
    .AutoFilter
End With
wbCSV.Close savechanges:=False
```

Comment: Thanks for the changes, this however does not fix the main issue which im just thinking is an excel issue now.